# Generating a custom archLinux image

Tags: arch-linux

I have a UEFI computer and I need to add 2 bin files and one folder to the iso live install image; this will provide me the wifi support at boot.

I followed this guide from the top: [Remastering the Install ISO](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Remastering_the_Install_ISO).

The problem is that I can't understand how to do the last part of the guide where it explains how to make it UEFI bootable form a USB stick.
After making the changes in the way explained I generated the new iso image through the commmand listed on the wiki:

```
genisoimage -l -r -J -V "ARCH_201209" -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -c isolinux/boot.cat -o ~/arch-custom.iso ~/customiso
```

The last step I have done is this:

```
isohybrid output.iso
```

After that I have pulled the iso to the usb stick using dd, but the custom archLinux won't boot.

The part that I don't understand is this:

> An alternative to genisoimage plus isohybrid can be derived from the
> xorriso run of mkarchiso.
>
> ```
> $ iso_label="ARCH_201209"
> $ xorriso -as mkisofs \
>        -iso-level 3 \  
>        -full-iso9660-filenames \
>        -volid "${iso_label}" \
>        -eltorito-boot isolinux/isolinux.bin \
>        -eltorito-catalog isolinux/boot.cat \
>        -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table \
>        -isohybrid-mbr ~/customiso/isolinux/isohdpfx.bin \
>        -output arch-custom.iso \ 
>        ~/customiso
> ```
>
> Option -isohybrid-mbr needs an MBR template file. Most probably there
> is already such a file /isolinux/isohdpfx.bin in the original ISO,
> which matches the SYSLinux version used in the ISO. Only if this file
> is missing in the copied ISO content, it has to be cut out of the
> original ISO image file, before above xorriso run is performed:
>
> ```
> $ dd if=/path/to/archISO bs=512 count=1 of=~/customiso/isolinux/isohdpfx.bin
> ```
>
> If the original ISO supports bootability via EFI, this can be
> activated in the new ISO by inserting the following options between
> the lines "-isohybrid-mbr ..." and "-output ...":
>
> ```
>    -eltorito-alt-boot \
>    -e EFI/archiso/efiboot.img \
>    -no-emul-boot -isohybrid-gpt-basdat \
> ```
>
> The file /EFI/archiso/efiboot.img is a FAT filesystem image file. If
> it is missing in the original ISO, then there was no EFI support in
> that ISO.
>
> The newly created ISO image arch-custom.iso is found in the home
> directory. You can write the ISO image to a USB stick as explained in
> USB Installation Media. Alternatively you can burn the ISO image on a
> CD, DVD, or BD with your preferred software. On Arch, that is covered
> in the article about burning an ISO image.

Answer (score 1):

`archiso` is the official iso-maker package from [Archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/archiso). You can either build a raw image of Archlinux at day-0, or build a completely customized iso from scratch (almost) and add packages, kernel-modules, build directives, folders, users, etc...

It may help you get a working image out-of-the-box of archlinux, plus the advantage of being customizable to your needs. The given image both support MBR & UEFI.